# audio error in vmware running mac os x

Tags: audio, cocos2d-iphone, vmware

simple synchronous loading of an audio file (.mp3) in a cocos2d app makes my vmware disconnect the sound.

the error is display bottom right, saying 'error in creating sound stream; sound is disconnected'

i read that it might be cause of my vmware's version (mine is 8) but I'm looking for a fix, not to downgrade to another version.

before i get that error, the sound on the system works just fine (youtube, etc)

the exact code im calling is..

```
    [CDSoundEngine setMixerSampleRate: CD_SAMPLE_RATE_MID];
[[CDAudioManager sharedManager] setResignBehavior: kAMRBStopPlay autoHandle:Yes];
soundEngine = [SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine];
[soundEngine preloadBackgroundMusic:@"somemp3.mp3"];
[soundEngine playBackgroundMusic:@"somemp3.mp3"];
```

maybe the bit rate is too high .. ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem in the vmware..